# where can I find service in mesos

Tags: mesos, service-discovery

I'm trying to use mesos to build a cluster scales dynamically according to Network loads.

A service discovery mechanism is needed to find those apps deployed by mesos.

There are some tools, but I want to know more about the detail. Does mesos have some api that I could list&find current services and their endpoint (ip:port)?  Or I have to write my app that it will push info into some database(sql, zookeeper) to tell others the address it's listening on?

There is a "DiscoveryInfo" message in Mesos. Can I use this to do service discovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a "DiscoveryInfo" message in Mesos. Can I use this to do service discovery?

Definitely. Information about tasks ip and port could be obtained from [/master/state](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/state/). For example [Mesos DNS](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) and [mesos-consul](https://github.com/CiscoCloud/mesos-consul) works in that way, pooling Mesos for information about tasks and update registry.
If you are using Marathon you can use tools that sits on top of the marathon API

- [marathon-lb](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb)
- [traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik)
- [marathon-consul](https://github.com/allegro/marathon-consul/)

[DisocveryInfo Design Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tpnjfHsa5Joka23CqgGppqnK0jODcElBvTFUBBO-A38/edit#heading=h.4wpt5efsi44n)

Comment: then how does this work? each task reports its status[ip:port] to the master, the mesos master collects info together. tools like Mesos DNS, mesos-consul keep polling master about these info?

Comment: When framework is accepting an offer above resources like CPU and MEM it declares which ports are required to run specific task. That's how Mesos knows about IPs and ports (it gets more complicated when you use SDN e.g. Calico). Then the only way to get this info is to pull it from master as Mesos events were not implemented yet.

Comment: Thank you. Another question is that the DiscoveryInfo is sent as part of the TaskInfo or ExecutorInfo, at that time the scheduler doesn't know whether the task will succeed, if the service failed to start or failed in the middle of running, who's responsible to clean the discoveryinfo, Or the tools that collect discoveryInfo should ignore info of tasks that is not running?

Comment: When tasks ends, executor sends that info to Mesos Agent which pass it to Mesos Master and task is moved from `tasks` to `completed_tasks`. So state in Mesos DNS will be updated by next sync.

Comment: So using the DiscoveryInfo mechanism, the task itself doesn't need to handle the service registration, the scheduler and the mesos framework does that, right? But currently I think that if I use task written by my own, using zookeeper to do the service discovery seems better.